# Kubernetes and logs from localhost with promtail

Tags: kubernetes, devops, grafana, grafana-loki, promtail

I have kubernetes installed on a viral machine. I have put grafana,loki and promtail with helm charts on it.I want to take logs from /var/log/syslog on the virtual machine.

I tried

```
extraScrapeConfigs: |
      - job_name: syslog
         syslog:
           listen_address: 0.0.0.0:1514
           label_structured_data: yes
           labels:
             job: "syslog"
         relabel_configs:
           - source_labels: ["__syslog_connection_ip_address"]
             target_label: "ip_address"
           - source_labels: ["__syslog_message_severity"]
             target_label: "severity"
           - source_labels: ["__syslog_message_facility"]
             target_label: "facility"
           - source_labels: ["__syslog_message_hostname"]
             target_label: "host"
```

as I added with rsyslog.conf on VM     *_*@nodeip:1514
but nothing happens.Any idea how it can happen

Comment: did you check if promtail is running ?